# Is every Hasse diagram connected?

Tags: order-theory

Is every Hasse diagram connected?

In other words - is some antichain subset of a poset, a poset in its own right?

I ask because I see no connectedness condition in the definition, but never seem to see disconnected Hasse diagrams.

Comment: I haven't really a great understanding of this concept, but i think that it is possible, like {2,3,9,27}... (A, /). Here probably 2 is not connected to anyone else, I am not sure this just what I am thinking.      I will be happy if someone figure out that this is wrong and let me know what's wrong here

Comment: Yes, an anti-chain is a poset too. So a poset doesn't have to be connected. To see it, notice that an anti-chain is a poset where the order relation is equality (which is trivially an order relation); clearly, an anti-chain is not connected, except if it has at most one element.